# #1130 - Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Tags: mysql, permissions

I issued a command of `DROP USER 'root'@'localhost'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO 'root'@'%';`in PhpMyAdmin, immediately after the execution, I was forced out PhpMyAdmin,I got an error `#1130 - Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server`, how to resolve my problem?

Comment: Do you have any important information in this database installation?

Comment: Yes, I have many tables.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://www.webyog.com/faq/content/23/36/en/i-get-error-1130-host-is-not-allowed-to-connect-or-access-denied-or-could-not-connect-.html

Answer (score 5):

Open up a terminal.

```
$ mysql -u root --host=127.0.0.1 -p<yourpassword>
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 521
Server version: 5.1.38yes-debug yes

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY "<yourpassword>";
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.22 sec)

mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)
```

This should fix your problem ;).

Answer (score 1):

mysql treats % and localhost differently.  You need grant all privileges to `'root'@'localhost'` as well.

Answer (score 1):

On your server run mysql from command line:

```
mysql -u root -p -h localhost -P 3306
```

Then run this command in mysql shell:

```
>use mysql
>GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
>FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Have a nice time.

Comment: One sure fire way to bring yourself to the attention of the system is to post identical answers to questions - please don't. Also from a security point of view allowing root to access from anywhere isn't great either.

Answer (score 0):

Combine dlo's answer with Darren Chamberlain's.  The reason for this is that the special meaning that 'localhost' has in MySQL is that it signifies to use the local unix socket (mysql.sock) vs the TCP socket.  This is why specifying 127.0.0.1 as the host will get you in so that you can fix the situation; it signifies to the MySQL client to use the TCP socket.